# Installing libtiff.so.3 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shared-library, libtiff

I need to run dtk (http://trackvis.org/) on my ubuntu 14.04 but when I try to execute dtk I get the error

`error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried Installing libtiff.so.4 as somebody suggested but the problem continues and I still get the same error. When I try to run `sudo apt-get libtiff.so.4` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtiff4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 101 not upgraded.
```

How can I install this tiff package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.3` (Replace `x86-64-linux-gnu` with `i386-linux-gnu` if you are on `i386`), but note that the program may not run due to different library symbols.

The last update seems to have been in 2011, which implies that the software isn't under active development, and the fact that the source code doesn't seem to be available online complicates issues. If you can get the source code, you can compile it locally and make sure it runs correctly.